# Extracting registry information from files in c:\windows\system32\Config* and profile ntuser.dat

Tags: windows-xp, windows, windows-registry

I have an old windows disk that got winrot under Win Pro XP/32.  I installed a new disk and did a fresh install of Win 7/64.  After that successfully completed, I reattached the old windows disk.

I'd like to retrieve certain registry settings from the older Win Pro XP/32 system for possible integration into my new Win 7/64 system for some of the reinstalled applications.

So the problem: I know that my user settings are contained in ntuser.dat and the other pieces of the registry are contained in files located in the old X:\windows\system32\Config*.  How do I examine or dump the old registry given that I have all these files available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within Windows it is pretty easy to do with the Registry editor.  Just load the [file as a hive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759303(WS.10).aspx).

- Open up regedit.
- Click onto the HKEY_USERS hive.
- Click **File** and **Load Hive**.
- You will be asked for a name, use something that is not used like 'TempReg'.
- Once the hive is loaded you can browse into HKEY_USERS\TempReg (or whatever name you used).
- When you are done, browse to the top of the hive you loaded and use the File, and **Unload Hive** to disconnect from that file.

> use ntuser.dat for the HKEY_USER hive
>   file then?

When you load a hive it appears as if it was within the existing hive, that is why you give it a name.  The ntuser.dat is the file that stores HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  You can only load a hive if you have HKEY_USERS or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE selected, but it doesn't really matter which one.  I like to have HKEY_USERS selected because it is almost no confusion between the hive I loaded at the other per-sid keys that are in HKEY_USERS.file then?

Comment: use ntuser.dat for the HKEY_USER hive file then?